# Python Pandas finding multiple column titles which exist in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find all column titles from a list of column titles which exist in a dataframe (and output all which exist as a dictionary for use in a tkinter dropdown menu).

For example, say i have a list of columns:

```
Options = ['title3', 'title5', 'title6']
```

and the dataframe has columns:

```
title1   title4   title3    title6
```

I would need the output to be:

```
choices = {'title3', 'title6'}.
```

The only way i currently have this working is inelegant:

```
if 'title1' in df1:
    choices = { 'title1'}

if 'title1' in df1 and 'title5' in df1:
    choices = { 'title1', 'title5'}
```

ect.

If anyone knows of a better way for me to get the result I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['title1','title4','title3','title6'])
Options = ['title3', 'title5', 'title6']
choices = df.columns.intersection(Options).tolist()
print (choices)
['title3', 'title6']
```